# Getting collections of data Laravel Eloquent doubts

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I have four tables in database and one Eloquent model for each table. Tables are:[image]

How to retrieve `items` from one `category` and get collection of `itemProperties` for each `item`, so that when `item` don't have all *properties* which `category` have, the rest of properties **exists** in collection and values for that properties are empty strings or something like that?

For example:

in table *category* i have  entry

- cats

in table *category_properties* i have entries

- color of eyes
- length of tail
- shape of ears

In table *items* i have entry

- Garfield

and in *item_properties* I have only one entry

- green

related to **Garfield** in *items* table and **color of eyes** in *category_properties*.

How to get `[ Garfield => [ 'color of eyes' => 'green', 'length of tail' => ' ', 'shape of ears' => ' ']]`, instead of `[Garfield => [ 'color of eyes' => 'green']]`

I can easily get expected results in mysql by joining tables item_properties and category_properties, but i don't know how to do the same with Eloquent and Laravel collections.

Is there something similar to sql join in eloquent?

Comment: check joins: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#joins

Answer (score 1):

Your description is a bit hard to understand. Im assuming you are trying to get `items` with `item_properties` from a `category`? It's best that you avoid using `raw joins` in Laravel, and use the `Model` instead.

Now, each of your `Model` create a relationship (Eloquent Relationship).

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships

And then you can use `Eager Loading`

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

---

I hope you've read the links I sent you.

Example:

**Category Model:**

```
public function items(){
  return $this->hasMany('App\Item', 'category_id', 'id');
}
public function categoryProperties(){
  return $this->belongsTo('App\CategoryProperty', 'category_id', 'id');
}
```

**Item Model:**

```
public function categories(){
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'category_id', 'id');
}

public function itemProperties(){
  return $this->hasMany('App\ItemProperty', 'item_id', 'id');
}
```

**ItemProperty Model:**

```
  public function items(){
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Item', 'item_id', 'id');    
}

public function categoryProperties(){
      return $this->belongsTo('App\CategoryProperty', 'property_id', 'id');
    }
```

**CategoryProperty Model:**

```
  public function itemProperties(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\ItemProperty', 'property_id', 'id');
    }
public function categories(){
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'category_id', 'id');
}
```

**Controller:**

```
$data = Item::with(['categories.categoryProperties','categories.categoryProperties.itemProperties'])->get();
```

Comment: I'm already using Eloquent models. I agree that question is pretty confusing, so I added an simplified example of what I want to achieve.

Comment: How did it go??

Comment: I decided not to use Eloquent for retrieving data, instead I did it with query builder, and I got data in much more suitable shape for printing in html table. I will add solution as answer a little bit later.

Comment: Okay good to hear. For future references, once your data has lots in numbers, adding joins slows down the query (well duuh), its best to use Model's relationship. It may be different at first, but it requires constant practice. You have eager loading, you can constrain it to only specific values etc. Good luck!